# Open popup as new tab

Tags: javascript, popup, tabs

Is it possible in Javascript to open a popup in a new tab of the browser? I don't care if the solution is not cross browser. 
I know the HTML solution with the target attribute but i must do it in javascript beacause i need to do it automatically without any click.

Comment: How's the HTML solution with the target attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really, it's a browser setting. In IE7 it's under Tools > Internet Options > (Tabs) Settings > When a popup is encountered...

Answer (score 0):

This is small demo where you can open a pop up either as a new tab or on top of the parent window.

Visit jsfiddle.net/shadowstrike/VhNyG/6